# Unable to access the module error while trying to simulate a simple PLC Lad program

Tags: simulation, plc

I am learning PLC and trying to simulate a simple program on Schematic Manager. But I'm having this error that says `Unable to access the module CPU314c-2DP via the online interface`. How can I solve it?

[image]

Comment: This would probably best be pursued with support resources or documentation for this tool.  It's unclear if it is trying to access a network resource, local simulator, or hardware, but you'll need to figure out which, if that is supposed to be available to you, and if it is, why it is not reachable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One "trick" that often works is to type some of the exact error message into a search engine (with quotes around it) and see what comes up. In your case I find [this](https://support.industry.siemens.com/tf/WW/en/posts/s-plcsim/48443?page=0&pageSize=10) in the Siemens PLC forum:

"I go to Options->Set PG/PC interface and select PC Adapter(MPI)...After that, PLCSIM going to work... "